# SAS Studio issue - mySASObjectServer access denied

Tags: sas, sas-studio

I have an issue with SAS Studio v9.04 running on Ubuntu 20.04,

The server run well except when a user try to login it doesn’t work it says :

The launch of server mySASObjectServer for user xxxxxx failed. Access denied.

I tried with other users and the same thing happen,

Answer (score 1):

It was a file / folder access issue,

The SAS Studio need to have the valid chown (owner) and chmod (access). So even if you do chmod -R 777 to make a test it will not work. You really need to be careful with the chown and chmod.

You can also run these script to adjust the chmod chown accordingly :

```
./SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/misc/deployment/setuid.sh
./SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/utilities/bin/setuid.sh
./SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/dbcs/utilities/bin/setuid.sh
```